# Azure ADB2C - Authorization flow with PKCE not working from postman

Tags: azure, postman, azure-ad-b2c

I have created ADB2C tenant and registered application. When I try to get access token using 'Auth code with PKCE' flow from postman using steps mentioned [here](https://vmsdurano.com/requesting-access-token-from-azure-b2c-with-pkce-using-postman/) I am getting below error.

[image]

Registered application:
[image]

Scope:
[image]

Permission granted:

[image]

UPDATE:
Issue was resolved just by restarting postman tool. Could be related to some cache or cookies.

Comment: What did you put for scope parameter in postman? Did you grant admin consent in the API permissions menu for this scope?

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT: I have attached screenshot for your reference. Same scope I am passing into postman.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT - It's resolved, there was some issue with postman cache seems like. I restarted postman and it started working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

•   I also followed the same link that you have posted in your question and entered the values as below to get the access token and the refresh token for the Authorization code with PKCE request through Postman and it was successful as it returned me the refresh token as well as the access token. I also gave the scope of the application created the admin consent for accessing the application’s API further which I also stopped getting any issues in Postman. Also, you can clear the cookies any time whenever you use the Postman for getting any new tokens through the Authorization code with PKCE method. Though, it was good for you that when you restarted the Postman application, it successfully worked. It might be because your Postman application was pending for a restart post background application updates.

[image: Postman - 1]
[image: Postman - 2]
[image: Postman - 3]
[image: Postman - 4]
[image: Postman - 5]